# List<T> extension method First, Second, Third....Nth

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I want to access the first, second, third elements in a list. I can use built in `.First()` method for accessing first element.

My code is as follows:

```
Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>> pList = new Dictionary<int, Tuple<int, int>>();  

var categoryGroups = pList.Values.GroupBy(t => t.Item1);
var highestCount = categoryGroups  
                   .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())  
                   .Select(g => new { Category = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })  
                   .First();  

var 2ndHighestCount = categoryGroups  
                      .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())  
                      .Select(g => new { Category = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })  
                      .GetNth(1);  

var 3rdHighestCount = categoryGroups  
                      .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())  
                      .Select(g => new { Category = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })  
                      .GetNth(2);  

twObjClus.WriteLine("--------------------Cluster Label------------------");
twObjClus.WriteLine("\n");  

twObjClus.WriteLine("Category:{0} Count:{1}",  
                    highestCount.Category, highestCount.Count);  
twObjClus.WriteLine("\n");
twObjClus.WriteLine("Category:{0} Count:{1}",  
                     2ndHighestCount.Category, 2ndHighestCount.Count);  
// Error here i.e. "Can't use 2ndHighestCount.Category here"
twObjClus.WriteLine("\n");  

twObjClus.WriteLine("Category:{0} Count:{1}",  
                     3rdHighestCount.Category, 3rdHighestCount.Count);  
// Error here i.e. "Can't use 3rdHighestCount.Category here"
twObjClus.WriteLine("\n");
```

I have written extension method `GetNth()` as:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> GetNth<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, int n)
{
   if (n < 0)
      throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("n");
      if (n > 0){
         int c = 0;
         foreach (var e in list){
            if (c % n == 0)
            yield return e;
            c++;
         }
      }
}
```

- Can I write extension methods as `.Second()`, `.Third()` similar to
  built in method `.First()` to access second and third indices?

Comment: `OrderByDescending(...).Select(....).Take(3)`

Comment: Do you want just the element at index N, or every Nth element (like every third, so a list of 9 would get you 3 results)? Because that's what your `GetNth` method is doing.

Comment: What errors are you talking about?

Comment: I've commented in the code i.e. the errors

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen I only want same as I'm getting by using `.First()` method

Comment: @Taufel: Then my answer is what you're looking for. I don't get how you ended up using `%` in your implementation if you didn't want "every Nth"...

Comment: @Taufel You enumerate the same IEnumerable again and again. Just do it once , take the top 3 and store it somewhere...

Comment: I don't need each 3 from each IEnumerable, as I only need First Second and Third from the list

Comment: @Eser: You should post that as an answer because it's the correct way to do it. I didn't look closely enough.

Comment: @Taufel I think you don't get me. Start with `pList`, do your groupby, orderby etc then take 3 items. that's all.

Comment: But I need all the three items separately as `.ElementAt()` method worked for me instead of writing `GetNth()` method

Comment: @Taufel Do whatever you want.... I quit

Comment: Sorry if you minded, I expressed what I found

Comment: Is anything wrong with this question? @Downvoters ? Amazing to see that some people up vote and some do down !

Comment: Here's a [blog post](http://scotthannen.org/blog/2016/06/25/extension-methods.html) on how to write extensions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since @Eser gave up and doesn't want to post the *correct* way as an answer, here goes:

You should rather do the transforms once, collect the results into an array, and then get the three elements from that. The way you're doing it right now results in code duplication as well as grouping and ordering being done multiple times, which is inefficient.

```
var highestCounts = pList.Values
                    .GroupBy(t => t.Item1)
                    .OrderByDescending(g => g.Count())  
                    .Select(g => new { Category = g.Key, Count = g.Count() })  
                    .Take(3)
                    .ToArray();

// highestCounts[0] is the first count
// highestCounts[1] is the second
// highestCounts[2] is the third
// make sure to handle cases where there are less than 3 items!
```

As an FYI, if you some day need just the Nth value and not the top three, you can use [`.ElementAt`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.100).aspx) to access values at an arbitrary index.

Comment: I tried this way but that is what I faced the same issue where there are less than 3 items, got an exception

Comment: @Taufel: I'd just `foreach` through the list to print the results. The printing part is copied and pasted too in your current code. If you insist on copying and pasting that too, put some ifs to check the length of the array.

Comment: You don't need to put any ifs inside the foreach loop. You do know what a foreach does right?

Comment: I think I am very lucky by not posting an answer, when watching these comments :) (@MattiVirkkunen you are also lucky for getting +6 for nothing)

Comment: @MattiVirkkunen yeah I got it, no ifs needed

Comment: @Eser is only for comment the commenting, instead of guiding posting an answer straight forward

Comment: @Taufel: I don't think so. He told you the exact same thing as in this answer as a comment to your original question. You just didn't read it thoroughly.

Comment: But you have elaborated the answer using same, he didn't

Comment: @Taufel: It was perfectly understandable to me and didn't need any elaboration.

Comment: But answer seekers are not as skilled as answer writers anyhow I apologize to him @Eser

Answer (score 1):

If what you're looking for is a single object, you don't need to write it yourself, because [a built-in method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299233(v=vs.100).aspx) for that already exists.

```
foo.ElementAt(1)
```

will get you the second element, etc. It works similarly to `First` and returns a single object.

Your `GetNth` method seems to be returning every Nth element, instead of just the element at index N. I'm assuming that's not what you want since you said you wanted something similar to `First`.

Comment: What is `foo`?  OP uses `GroupBy`s and `OrderByDescending`s, which results in `IEnumerable<T>`

Comment: @L.B: A standard [placeholder variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foobar) - surely you've seen foo and bar before?

Comment: I upvoted. Although I did post an example of how to write an extension method (which is what OP asked for) there's really no need for anything other than this. If we wanted a "safe" version we could do something like `.Skip(n).FirstOrDefault()` but that's short enough that it doesn't warrant its own function.

Comment: @ScottHannen You don't see that *real* problem is not an extension method, do you?

Comment: If taken directly at face value, the question is how to write an extension method. In this case answering that the extension methods already exist is a good answer. `Can I write extension methods as .Second(), .Third() similar to built in method .First() to access second and third indices?` There's more to the question but it's really a separate question. I think everyone is focusing on the question that matches the one in bold at the top of the page, which makes sense. The other question about how to fix an error is really just tacked on and should be a separate question.

Comment: @ScottHannen Continue to answer **Y** of [XY-problems](http://xyproblem.info/) But that wouldn't really help the OP (of course you can get some reps in the mean time....).